# How do I output an XML document object that is populated with SQL query data containing HTML content to an XML file in ColdFusion?

Tags: html, sql, xml, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have written a script in ColdFusion that grabs all of the HTML content for my website in a database table and creates an XML document object. Below is my code so far.

```
<!--- Get page info --->
<cfquery name="qPageInfo" datasource="#application.datasource#">
    SELECT top 800 id, title, info, app
    FROM sitePublic
</cfquery>

<cfdump var="#qPageInfo#">

<!--- Creating XML document object w/ sitePublic data --->
 <cfxml variable="xmlPageInfo">
    <page>
        <cfoutput query="qPageInfo">
            <id>#qPageInfo.id#</id>
            <pagecontent>#Trim("#XMLFormat(qPageInfo.info)#")#</pagecontent>
        </cfoutput>
    </page> 
 </cfxml>

 <!---<cfdump var="#xmlPageInfo#">--->

 <!--- Need to figure out how to output to a file --->
 <cffile action="write" file="%filepath%/webcontent.xml" output="#qPageInfo#">
```

I was able to successfully do a cfdump on the XML document object and it dumped all content for all web pages in the browser window.

However, the part I cannot seem to get working is the last line, `<cffile>` to output the XML data to an XML file. Below is the error I get when trying to run execute this.

> The expression has requested a variable or an intermediate expression result as a simple value. However, the result cannot be converted to a simple value. Simple values are strings, numbers, boolean values, and date/time values. Queries, arrays, and COM objects are examples of complex values.
>
> The most likely cause of the error is that you tried to use a complex value as a simple one. For example, you tried to use a query variable in a cfif tag.

I am new to ColdFusion so I could be leaving something out in my code, does anyone have an idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Nothing to do with your issue, but you do not need quotes or extra pound signs when nesting function calls. ie Use `#Trim( XMLFormat(qPageInfo.info) )#` instead of  `#Trim("#XMLFormat(qPageInfo.info)#")#`.

Comment: Shouldn't `output="#qPageInfo#"` be `output="#xmlPageInfo#"` You build the xml but then use the query output to write not the xml.

Comment: My apologies for the delayed response. Thank you Leigh and haxtbh for pointing those details out to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a large and small concern about this

**First**

```
<!--- Creating XML document object w/ sitePublic data --->
<cfxml variable="xmlPageInfo">
<page>
    <cfoutput query="qPageInfo">
        <id>#qPageInfo.id#</id>
        <pagecontent>#Trim("#XMLFormat(qPageInfo.info)#")#</pagecontent>
    </cfoutput>
</page> 
</cfxml>
```

This is going to generate lots and lots of `<id>` and `<pagecontent>` tags

Consider

```
<pagecontent id="#qPageInfo.id#">#Trim(XMLFormat(qPageInfo.info))#</pagecontent>
```

**Second**

```
<cffile action="write" file="%filepath%/webcontent.xml" output="#qPageInfo#">
```

Now the real problem, `qPageInfo` is the query. I suspect that you wanted to write the xml.

The simpler approach is to deal with the XML as a string

```
<cfsavecontent variable="xmlPageInfo">
<page>
    <cfoutput query="qPageInfo">
        <pagecontent id="#qPageInfo.id#">#Trim(XMLFormat(qPageInfo.info))#</pagecontent>
    </cfoutput>
</page> 
</cfsavecontent>


<cffile action="write" file="%filepath%/webcontent.xml" output="#xmlPageInfo#">
```

**OR**

If you want to make sure you are processing xml and not just a string that is xml

```
<cfxml variable="xmlPageInfo">
<page>
    <cfoutput query="qPageInfo">
        <pagecontent id="#qPageInfo.id#">#Trim(XMLFormat(qPageInfo.info))#</pagecontent>
    </cfoutput>
</page> 
</cfxml>


<cffile action="write" file="%filepath%/webcontent.xml" output="#ToString(xmlPageInfo)#">
```

Comment: Which approach did you end up using? `<cfsavecontent>` or `<cfxml>` ?

Comment: I used the `<cfxml>` method.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you posted the actual code with your question or not but you have `%` percent signs instead of `#` hash tags around your `filepath` variable.

This:

```
<cffile action="write" file="%filepath%/webcontent.xml" output="#qPageInfo#">
```

Should be this:

```
<cffile action="write" file="#filepath#/webcontent.xml" output="#xmlPageInfo#">
```

*updated to use the correct variable `xmlPageInfo` for writing the file as others have mentioned.*

Comment: Hi Miguel, thank you for your response. I should have made a comment on this. I just put the %filepath% there as a placeholder for me so I know to put the full file path later. Sorry about that.